# Can MySQL be installed as an embedded database with an offline application?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, sqlite

I was with the choice of SQLite as database for easy distribution of my offline c# desktop application (WPF / Winforms) but currently cornered to MySQL database due to IRD certification.

My main concern is that I want to know If I could use `MySQL` database for offline desktop application and distribute `.exe` via **URL** for easy unattended installation.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you chose SQLite over SQL Server Compact?

Comment: https://www.mysql.com/oem/

Comment: Apparently SQL Server Compact edition is deprecated by Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776328/port-sql-compact-to-windows-rt,

Comment: @HristoYankov yah... I heard that Compact edition is deprecated. IRD team restricted to use SQLite as client database. What should I do now?

Comment: Check this out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818437/embedded-mysql-server-c-sharp-wrapper

Answer (score 2):

As shown on SQLite's page [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), a client/server database like MySQL would work better for client/server applications, high-volume websites, very large datasets, or high concurrency. Nothing of this applies to your offline application, so you should use a database that was designed to be embedded (not necessarily SQLite).

MySQL has an [embedded server library](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/libmysqld.html) which can be linked directly into an application. When using C#, the MySQL library is linked into the .NET MySQL database driver, so using the embedded server would require recompiling this driver. And such linking will trigger MySQL's GPL license. And:

> The `libmysqld` embedded server library is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.17 and will be removed in MySQL 8.0.

It would be possible to install the standalone MySQL server yourself; this is described in [Installing MySQL on Microsoft Windows Using a noinstall Zip Archive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-install-archive.html).
However, this would still run the MySQL server as a separate process or service, and this could conflict with other installations on the machine; it would be your installer's responsibility to configure that MySQL instance correctly for whatever environment it encounters on the target machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Does the deprecation of `libmysqld` would affect in the development of my future application ? Wouldn't it be available in recent version than MySQL 5.7.17 ?

Comment: Ask Oracle what they mean by that …

Comment: Can you provide the link of that please