# How to install MySQL database in pendrive

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, usb-drive

I have to make C# desktop application with mysql Database that will be booted in a pendrive. Just like plug and play application. So I want to setup MySQL database in Pendrive.

Comment: You could probably ship `mysqld.exe` alongside your application, and launch in the background. But using a true embedded database like SQLite is going to be so much easier.

Comment: Have you considered serialising and deserialising your data? Depends how much input the user does but if it's working just off a usb then it's presumably only the one person input would change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715088/can-mysql-be-installed-as-an-embedded-database-with-an-offline-application